# Entity Framework: M-to-n: Read a linked entity from a list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I know my title isn't quite specific and I'm sure my question has already been asked somewhere but I don't know how to search for it.

I'm using asp.net MVC with Entity framework and I have the following model:

```
public class Receipt 
{        
    public int ReceiptId { get; set; }

    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    public int UseraccountId { get; set; }

    public int MessageId { get; set; }

    public virtual Useraccount Useraccount { get; set; }

    public virtual Message Message { get; set; }

}//end Receipt
```

A user has several Receipts.
I would like to get all messages from a specific user.

This is how I'm doing it so far:

```
//Get receipts of the logged in user
List<Receipt> receipts = UnitOfWork.ReceiptRepository.Get(
    u => u.UseraccountId == loggedInUser.UseraccountId).ToList<Receipt>();

//Get all messages of the receipts
List<Message> messages = new List<Message>();
foreach (Receipt receipt in receipts)
{
    messages.Add(receipt.Message);
}
```

Is there any better way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a link from Message to Receipt? I'm assuming from your Receipt class that it has a one-to-one relationship with your Message class. To be able to do this method, your Message class should look something like this:

```
public class Message
{
    public int MessageId {get; set;}
    //other properties here

    //these provide the backward link to the Receipt that "owns" the message
    public int ReceiptId {get; set;} 
    public virtual Receipt Receipt {get; set;} 
 }
```

Your model should recognize this link by having something like this (if you are using Code First)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Receipt>()
        .HasOptional(r => r.Message)
        .WithRequired(m => m.Receipt);
}
```

Your query should be done at the Repository level, specifically the **Message** repository because it will be the layer that has access to your database context. Your query could look something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Message> GetAllMessagesByUserId (int userId)
{
    return context.Set<Message>().Include(x => x.Receipt)
                          .Include (x => x.Receipt.Useraccount)
                          .Where (x => x.Receipt.Useraccount.UseraccountId == userId)
                          .ToList();
}
```

When you call UnitOfWork.MessageRepository.GetAllMessagesByUserId (loggedInUser.UseraccountId), it should return all messages that are linked to the user you are interested in.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I'm sorry for wering not very precicse when asking the question.

I've a useraccount which is linked to messages via receipts.

A message can have 1..n receipts (if I sent a message to 2 addressees, there will be 1 message, but 2 receipts. This is the basic idea behind it).
So the message doesn't have an ReceiptId.